# DynamoDB : dynamoDb mapper returns null for Boolean value

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a boolean in DynamoDB mapped as below in my code -

```
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isFlagged")
    public Boolean getFlagged() {
        return isFlagged;
    }
```

I always get a null when I query the table using dynamoDB  mapper. So I looked up some documentation and added the annotation -

```
  @DynamoDBConvertedBool(DynamoDBConvertedBool.Format.true_false)
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isFlagged")
    public Boolean getFlagged() {
        return isFlagged;
    }
```

I get an 'could not unconvert attribute' error. How can I fix this?

PS - I am a DynamoDB beginner, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that there is an issue with format of the data stored in DynamoDB.

First of all this is what DynamoDB expects:

> Boolean
>
> A Boolean type attribute can store either true or false.

Check data in tables actually matches this. Do you have items that don't have the "isFlagged" attribute? Are some of them null?

If you need to convert empty values/null values to boolean values you need to implement your custom converter, which has a ridiculously simple interface:

```
// Converts between String (DynamoDB side) and Boolean (application side)
public class MyBooleanConverter implements DynamoDBTypeConverter<String, Boolean> {

    // Add any checks/conversions you see fit:
    @Override
    // Convert to DynamoDB attribute
    public String convert(Boolean object) {
        return object.toString();
    }

    @Override
    // Convert from DynamoDB attribute
    public Boolean unconvert(String object) {
        // Parse as you see necessary here
        return Boolean.parse(object);
    }
}
```

Now annotate your attribute with your converter:

```
  @DynamoDBConvertedBool(converter = MyBooleanConverter.class)
  @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isFlagged")
  public Boolean getFlagged() {
     ...
  }
```

**P.S.**

You don't need to specify an attribute name if your method name matches your attribute name:

```
  @DynamoDBConvertedBool(converter = MyBooleanConverter.class)
  public Boolean isFlagged() {
     ...
  }
```

Should be enough. Also boolean getter should has isX format anyway.

Comment: Actually, I only have 2 records in the table and both of them have values. So if all the records do have valid values, there should not be a problem?

Comment: Should be fine, as long as you store data that can be correctly parsed by your converter. Make sure your converter stores data it can parse and that other applications that have access to the table generate data in the same format.

Comment: I would not need a custom converter if my database attribute is boolean and java object attribute is boolean too, right? Or do I still need a custom converter?

Comment: changing the getter name to be isX works for me. Wondering why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Annotation is:
@DynamoDBTypeConverted(converter = MyBooleanConverter.class)

return Boolean.valueOf(object);

Rest worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the annotation `@DynamoDBTyped`

```
@DynamoDBTyped(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.DynamoDBAttributeType.BOOL)
@DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "isFlagged")
private boolean isFlagged;
```